# How to set/reset property to react element at runtime

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Ok. Let's the make the question pretty simple.

I've a component named `ColorText`.

```
class ColorText extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return (<Text style={{color:this.props.color}}>{this.props.text}</Text>);
  }
}
```

and when I call

```
<ColorText color="red" text="I am red text"/>
```

It works.

[image]

Now, I've a function which returns the `ColorText` like this

```
 getGreenText = () => {
    return (<ColorText text="Default text" color="green"/>);
 }
```

and I want to reset the text property at runtime like this

```
const GreenText = this.getGreenText();
GreenText.props.text = "I am green text";
```

It doesn't work. and prints the *Default Text*

So, here is my question. **Is it possible to set/reset property of a react component at runtime ? What is the correct way?**

NOTE: I've googled a lot, couldn't find anything positive. If you have any doubt the question, ask me in the comments. Full source code can be available from [here](https://gist.github.com/theapache64/72c974986ba0fac469e8abab1efb6efe)

**Edit:**

I know it's could be accomplished by simply passing the variable to the method like this

```
getGreenText = (text) => {
    return (<ColorText text={text || "Default text"} color="green"/>);
}
```

but that's not how i want to get it accomplished. I want to set it via the object returned from the method. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the `React.cloneElement` can clone the object and insert new props with it.

```
let GreenText = React.cloneElement(this.getGreenText(),{
    text : 'I am green text'
});
```

Full working source code can be found here : [Gist](https://gist.github.com/theapache64/b1733719719b1e72575bc54b29f0b6e6)

Answer (score 1):

You can't. It's by design. If you try to do

```
GreenText.props.text = "I am green text";
```

It will throw an error because props are immutable.

Can you give a use case where you need to do something like that ? It should never be needed.

---

**Possible solution**

You could simply pass the text as an argument as follows:

```
getGreenText = (text) => {
    return (<ColorText text={text || "Default text"} color="green"/>);
}

render() {
    const GreenText = this.getGreenText("I am green text");
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <ColorText color="red" text="I am red text"/>
            {GreenText}
        </View>
    );
}
```

If you need to defer the update of the text you can simply use the state.

Otherwise you could achieve something as you want with `ref` (see: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: I know it'd work. but that's not how i want to get the property set. Is it possible to set it via the object returned.?

Comment: The question is the simplified version of a complex one. Actually, am trying to create a `Table` component which accepts `renderRow` , `widthsPerColumn`, and few other properties. I want to assign the `widthPerColumns` to the components returned from the `renderRow` method. I know, you might not have get the complex problem. that's why I simplified it with coor things. :/

Comment: I edited my answer. Direct update of the props as you want to do is not possible since they are immutable (it's by design). Can you provide a complete example of this? It seems to me that there is a clean solution for that.

Comment: Is it possible to create another element using `React.createElement` and copying all the props of the current object into it. ?

Comment: If you're ready to come in skype or something else, i can provide you the real example. The test example can be downloaded from here : https://gist.github.com/theapache64/72c974986ba0fac469e8abab1efb6efe

Comment: `renderRow: (item: ItemT, index: number) => ReactElement<RowPropTypes>,`

Comment: As i said, It's a complex function. You won't understand it with one paragraph.

Comment: Indeed, i'm sorry i can't help you without a complete example. But i'm pretty sure it  should be a more 'React' way to do this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173562/discussion-between-theapache64-and-alexandre-annic).

Comment: Thank you so much for you time. :)

Comment: I wish, but I can't pass so much time to help. Think about the solutions I posted. I'm sure you can found a better way.

Comment: Sure. Thanks again for spending your valueable time for me. I'll let you know once i found the solution.

Comment: I've found the solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/50969066/4370279 : I tried the `React.cloneElement`. :)